# sql/db questions on stackoverflow or dba

Tags: discussion

There's a DBA stackexchange site but I see a lot of SQL questions on StackoverFlow.  When do these questions belong on one site vs the other?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [DBA FAQ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq) has these items regarding SQL:

> If you have a question about...
>
> - **Advanced** Querying including window-functions dynamic-sql and query-performance
> - **Advanced Programming** in built-in server-side languages including stored-procedures and triggers.
>
> …then you're in the right place to ask your question!

And then:

> but, dba.se is *not* the right place to ask questions about...
>
> - Client-side programming - ask on Stack Overflow
> - Basic SQL - ask on Stack Overflow

So that's the cut-off: the DBA site welcomes advanced querying problems and server-side programming. Simple SQL, and anything not programmed inside the database itself isn't considered on topic.

Now obviously "simple"/"advanced" are relative terms, and complexe queries are also treated well on Stack Overflow. So the line isn't clear-cut.

In my opinion, the closer you are to the database engine (digging inside explain plans, tuning indexing strategies for complex/expensive operations, trying to hint the optimizer to tweak a path, actually installing a database or doing replication, backups, ...), the more you should think about posting on DBA rather than on Stack Overflow.

See also [What kind of questions are allowed on Database Administrators?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-kind-of-questions-are-allowed-on-database-administrators) on DBA's meta for a lengthy list of what sort of questions are welcome over there.

Comment: But what is the SO policy?  It sounds to me like you are saying SO does what DBA says instead of having its own policy.  For me if not SO for such queries, where?  Perhaps you can point out somewhere SO says yes SQL queries (particularly client SQL queries) are on topic?

Comment: @demongolem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql - over 200k questions. 15 asked in the last hour, none closed.

Comment: Just want to say first, I am not trying to be argumentative I am trying to provide clarity for future visitors.  So you are saying that because this is the way we have always done it, that's the way it is?  I would find it more helpful if we at least had a wiki question on SQL queries to be definitive on such matters.

Comment: "this is the way we have always done it, that's the way it is" - pretty much, like a lot of stuff here. Unless/until that way becomes problematic. I don't see a problem, DBA.SE isn't too drowned with SQL it doesn't handle, SO isn't drowned in DBA questions either.

Comment: @Mat, Seriously, following from your reasoning, what's the point of the DBA.SE branch then? Why not migrate DBA.SE back into Stackoverflow?

Comment: @Pacerier: I don't understand your comment. Why merge them? Distinct audiences and topics.

Comment: @Mat, I'm referring to your comment *"Now obviously "simple"/"advanced" are relative terms, and complex queries are also treated well on Stack Overflow."*, then shouldn't SQL questions be posted on stackoverflow and only leave the "administrative" stuff to DBA.SE?