# Do data integration questions belong on SO or DBA?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

[The DBA FAQ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq) lists "ETL" and "data warehousing" as on-topic, but I think most would agree that, say, a C# question regarding a SOAP API belongs on Stack Overflow.  So where's the line on integration questions?

I was considering asking a general question about integration, but I'd like to know the best place to ask it first.

Regarding "where is the line" for SQL questions, this was [asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172516/sql-db-questions-on-stackoverflow-or-dba) but no clear objective answer appeared.  We may not be able to do any better for this topic.

[The accepted answer to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113780/169512) suggests that it's a matter of the asker's perspective as much as anything.  To put it another way, would you the asker like answers from DBAs or developers?  This suggests that it may be valid to ask some questions on both sites, as there may be different valuable answers from each.

Answer (score 1):

Does your general question about integration contain any C# code and outline a specific problem with that code?  If it does, it will probably live quite happily on Stack Overflow.  If it doesn't, it's probably more appropriate on DBA.

Comment: Nope.  So your take is that integration questions belong on DBA unless they're clearly coding-related?

Comment: Questions about ETL and data warehousing absent any code are almost certainly off-topic on Stack Overflow.